# wait for http.request response before executing further

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I've made a user signup/signin system. The user can sign up through email or text. An activation key is then emailed or texted.

I have the following code:

```
    var activation_key_sent
    switch (signup_method) {
        case 'email':
            try {
                // send email
            } catch (error) {
                // handle errors
            }
        break
        case 'telephone':
            var text = await https.request({
                hostname: 'api.xxxx.com',
                port: xxx,
                path: 'xxxx',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            }, (res) => {
                res.setEncoding('utf8')
                res.on('data', (chunk) => {
                    if (parseInt(chunk) > 1) {
                        // query to log the error in the database
                        activation_key_sent = false
                    } else {
                        activation_key_sent = true
                    }
                })
            })
            text.write(querystring.stringify({
                USERNAME: 'xxxx',
                SECRET: 'xxxx',
                DESTINATION: 'xxxx',
                SENDER: 'xxxx',
                BODY: activation_key
            }))

            text.end()
        break

    }
    console.log(activation_key_sent)
```

The email part works fine. The problem is with the text part. When I send a text, I get a response (chunk) from the server. This is a number 1, or higher. 1 is OK, higher then 1 is an error.

When I execute this code, I see that console.log(activation_key_sent) is undefined. I guess I have to stop the code somewhere to wait for the response. I want to wait at res.on('data') (I think). I want to wait for the response, if the response = 1 -> query, if not, go further with the code.

I guess I need async/await somewhere. I've tried adding async to res.on('data', async (chunck) => ... and await chunk, but that didn't work. Does anyone have an idea how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## UPDATE:

Try this way of wrapping your httpsRequest in a promise. The main method here is the method your switch statement is embedded in.

```js
const respCode = 11;

async function main() {
  var responseCode = await new Promise(res => {
    httpsRequest(res);
  });
  // now you have responseCode from outside the callback
  console.log(responseCode);
}


// function with the similar signature to https.request
function httpsRequest( /*other args, */ callback) {
// mock your http request with the constant respCode from above
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback(respCode);
  }, 1000);
}

main();
```

Await is generally used to unwrap promises from a callback style syntaxinto an async await syntax like this:
`doRequest().then (response => {})` into `var response = await doRequest()`.

You don't have a promise like that.

Because of this, your await doesn't really do anything as you use the `https.request` method with a callback (`(res) =>`). If you want to insert functionality, it has to be in the callback method like this:

```
    var activation_key_sent
    switch (signup_method) {
        case 'email':
            try {
                // send email
            } catch (error) {
                // handle errors
            }
        break
        case 'telephone':
            var text = await https.request({
                hostname: 'api.xxxx.com',
                port: xxx,
                path: 'xxxx',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            }, (res) => {
                res.setEncoding('utf8')
                res.on('data', (chunk) => {
                    if (parseInt(chunk) > 1) {
                        // query to log the error in the database
                        activation_key_sent = false
                    } else {
                        activation_key_sent = true
                    }
                })
                console.log(activation_key_sent)
            })
            text.write(querystring.stringify({
                USERNAME: 'xxxx',
                SECRET: 'xxxx',
                DESTINATION: 'xxxx',
                SENDER: 'xxxx',
                BODY: activation_key
            }))

            text.end()
        break

    }
```

Furthermore, if you insist on using `https.request` with the async / await pattern, that is a whole another topic:
https://medium.com/@gevorggalstyan/how-to-promisify-node-js-http-https-requests-76a5a58ed90c

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Is there another way (another library, I don't need to use https.request) so I can access the activation_key_sent variable outside of the callback? I kinda need it somewhere else.